# Webcam access in safari using jquery

Tags: php, jquery

```
 if(navigator.webkitGetUserMedia) { // WebKit-prefixed
        alert(1);
        navigator.webkitGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
          track = stream.getTracks()[0];
          video_camera_capture.src = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(stream);
          video_camera_capture.play();
        }, errBack);
      }
      else if(navigator.getUserMedia) { // Standard
        alert(2);
        navigator.getUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream) {
          track = stream.getTracks()[0];
          video_camera_capture.src = stream;
          video_camera_capture.play();
        }, errBack);
      }else if(navigator.mozGetUserMedia) { // Firefox-prefixed
        alert(3);
        navigator.mozGetUserMedia(videoObj, function(stream){
          track = stream.getTracks()[0];
          video_camera_capture.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);
          video_camera_capture.play();
        }, errBack);
      }
```

I want a solution to access webcam in safari using jquery. The above codes are used for chrome, mozilla and normal browsers. So if anyone know solution please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Html 5 Video not support in window safari. In MAC OSit will properly work